# Deploy as production server

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a project in Git with Dockerfile wich describe the production server. Code and Dockerfile is build by Jenkins on special machine (physical CI server). After successful build I would to deploy this image in container on **remote** host (another physical deploy sever).

What is the easiest way of doing this? Is there any Jenkins plugings to deploy image/container on remote Docker (on another machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you have the remote host poll Jenkins to see if the latest build was successful. Perhaps a cron will help you schedule it. Then if the latest status == "SUCCESS" pull the latest git/docker image and run.

I found this script on serverfault.com, https://serverfault.com/questions/309848/how-can-i-check-the-build-status-of-a-jenkins-build-from-the-command-line

The first parameter of the script is the name of the project on Jenkins. The script will connect to your Jenkins instance, see jenkinsURL parameter, and check to see if the latest build was successful.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# author: ajs
# license: bsd
# copyright: re2


import json 
import sys
import urllib2

jenkinsUrl = "https://jenkins.example.com/job/"


if len( sys.argv ) > 1 :
    jobName = sys.argv[1]
else :
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    jenkinsStream   = urllib2.urlopen( jenkinsUrl + jobName + "/lastBuild/api/json" )
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print "URL Error: " + str(e.code) 
    print "      (job name [" + jobName + "] probably wrong)"
    sys.exit(2)

try:
    buildStatusJson = json.load( jenkinsStream )
except:
    print "Failed to parse json"
    sys.exit(3)

if buildStatusJson.has_key( "result" ):      
    print "[" + jobName + "] build status: " + buildStatusJson["result"]
    if buildStatusJson["result"] != "SUCCESS" :
        exit(4)
else:
    sys.exit(5)

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: It may be a solution but I use Github Oauth plugin which redirect me to github page if I am not authorized

Also our corporate standards do not let to have ssh connection on deploy server... So I put Jenkins in docker container which also run`s on the same deploy server in `--privileged` mode to be able to run docker inside docker. And code from Jenkins is deployed on host by ssh